# How to click add to cart button as per the given html?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

My Selenium Python script is unable to click add to cart button.

**HTML code**:

```html
<input type="button" value="Add to cart" title="Add to cart" 
class="button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button" onclick="AjaxCart.addproducttocart_catalog
('/addproducttocart/catalog/18/1/1');return false;">
```

**My script**:

```python
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/input[3]")
inputElement.click()
```

This is the error I get:

```
File "C:\Users\Raghav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input type="button" value="Add to cart" title="Add to cart" class="button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button" onclick="AjaxCart.addproducttocart_catalog('/addproducttocart/catalog/18/1/1');return false;"> is not clickable at point (1334, 635). Other element would receive the click: <div class="page-loader" style="opacity: 0.924946;">...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the HTML you have shared to click on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.button-2.product-box-add-to-cart-button[title='Add to cart']"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button' and @title='Add to cart']"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Is there a reason to post the same answer? Only the difference is the locator, what does not help to solve the issue, because the error shows that OPs `xPath` is right.

Comment: The locator is cleaner in this solution. It's not the best practice to travel multiple indices without a clean ***attribute locator***, unless you have to. Also, an answer is more useful with an explanation as @DebanjanB has provided.

Comment: @PixelEinstein make sense, thank you for explanation. Will try to give more explained answers in the future

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/input[3]")))
element.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I am trying it now, looks like i am doing something wrong. Will let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is correct, It get value but it is just not able to click. For that you can use action method to click it.

You need to Replace click event with action class, which will solve this Exception

**Action method to Click :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element("Element to Click").click().perform()
```

But, You have used absolute xpath which is never good idea to use. You need to use Relative xpath like following or as **@DebanjanB** has mentioned.

**Relative xpath instead of Absolute:**

```
//input[@title='Add to cart' and @value='Add to cart']
```